# Zend framework 2 best practice helper/library

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm using Zend Framework 2 and I need to implement a class I've built to deal with images and I will be using it in quite a few places within my project.

I was wondering where could a put such file, is it a library? a helper? do I need to register it? What's the best practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

For maximum flexibility, you should register the class to the service locator as a new service. This will allow you to easily inject dependencies, create it using a factory etc.

If the 'service' is something that could be useful in the view (or controller) as a plugin, then create a new independent plugin where you inject the new service into it. The view helper would provide publicly accessible methods that would simply proxy to the service.

This way the service can be utilized elsewhere in the application, not just as a 'view helper'.